# A story starring agreeable, fuzzy blob/animal creatures

Tags: identification-request

This was a childrens novel with infrequent illustrations from maybe 10+ years ago. I think it was set in Australia or maybe South Australia? I'm going to start by describing the aforementioned creatures, as they're probably the most distinct and recognisable part.

- They're sorta like slightly taller Furbys, more egg-shaped, with distinct arms.
- They're especially squishy and stretchy.
- They always, always agree to things. Saying "Oh, no doubt, no doubt" and other things. It's implied to be more just a derpyness/innocence to them.
- I want to say that their names began with a "Woo" or maybe ended in "ble"?

These things were targeted by another made up race, and I want to call them the Gretchins or something. The latter species tries to enslave them, eat them, etc. but all of their plans fail.

At the climax of the book,

> The blobs all fuse into one giant version of themselves.

That's all I really remember, other than the book in general being REALLY weird.